# I have created one field using product form field for my price i want save my field value at product creation time from backend magento2

Tags: magento2, product, adminform, ui-form

I have created Custom form field for product creation and edit time, i want save my price.i have created one new tab for product form .i want save my custom price same as price option.  my input field is display on product creation form.

inside my observer i have added code

```
namespace Custom\Myprice\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use  Custom\Myprice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomFieldset;


**class implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $resource;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->resource = $resource;
      }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $data = $this->request->getPostValue();
            if (isset($data['product']['myprice']))
            { 
                $exampleTextField =   $product->getData(CustomFieldset::FIELD_NAME_TEXT);
                what should i do for save price in field
            }
        }
}**
```

I have create my-price custom product attribute from back-end  same as form name fields for save price in database table "catalog_product_entity_decimal"

is it necessary to create custom product attribute for save value in database table "catalog_product_entity_decimal"
My observer is called and post value inside observer but not able to save in table

how to save my custom field value in database table "catalog_product_entity_decimal"  give me solution.

Comment: I have solved issue for created form field i have created same product attribute from back-end and assign to attribute set.
 i have added code inside execute function 
<pre>
     $product = $observer->getProduct();
$exampleTextField = $product->getData(CustomFieldset::FIELD_NAME_TEXT);
   if($exampleTextField !='')
   {
                   $product->setData('myprice', $exampleTextField); 
   $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'myprice');
   }
</pre>
 able to save  value for table catalog_product_entity_decimal now i want get price  and disply for input.